# React re-render with useState- data updates, but screen doesn't update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, rendering

I'm practicing playing with fixing/filtering poorly formatted JSONs and running into an annoying issue with displaying the resolved data.

Essentially, it should re-render after pressing the Clean button and show the updated values. The console.logs show the correct/updated data, but the re-render does not occur.

I feel like I'm just tired and not seeing something silly or forgetting something about async here. Suggestions would be great!

```
function App() {
  const [uglyData, setUglyData] = useState(_uglyData);
  

  const keyCleaner = async (arr) => {
    const newData = await cleanupUndefinedKeys(arr);
    // console.log(newData);
    setUglyData(newData);
    return newData;
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1>List of Users</h1>

      <div>
        {uglyData.map((user) => {
          return <User key={user.id} user={user} />;
        })}
        {/* <User user={uglyData[0]} /> */}
      </div>

      <div>
        <button onClick={() => keyCleaner([...uglyData])}>
          Clean undefined and empty string values
        </button>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
export const cleanupUndefinedKeys = async (arr) => {
    const returnArr = [];
    
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for(let key in arr[i]) {
            if((key === 'email' || key === 'username' || key === 'roles') && (arr[i][key] === 'undefined' || arr[i][key] === '')) {
                if(key !== 'roles') {
                    arr[i][key] = null;
                } else arr[i][key] = [];
            } else if(key === 'profile' && (arr[i][key] === 'undefined' || arr[i][key] === '')) {
                for(let profileKey in arr[i][key]) {
                    if((profileKey === 'name' || profileKey === 'about' || profileKey === 'dob' || profileKey === 'address' || profileKey === 'company') && (arr[i][key][profileKey] === undefined || arr[i][key][profileKey] === '')) {
                        arr[i][key][profileKey] = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        returnArr.push(arr[i]);
    };

    return returnArr;
}
```

Comment: You're mutating the state, and when that's done React might not see that it needs to re-render. Never mutate state in React.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Could you point out where I'm doing that? I've been up about 18 hours and just not seeing it atm. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: In `arr[i][key] = null` and `arr[i][key][profileKey] = null;` you are mutating the state

Comment: Oh damn, thank you. Much appreciated.